# Is it possible to shift the color of a div using css?

Tags: html, css

**Update**: The original phrasing of this question was vague so i've modified it to better express what i'm asking.

Lets say I have two divs

```
<div class='button'>A</div>
<div class='button green-button'>A</div>
```

with the following styles:

```
div.button {
  /* define position,  size, etc ...*/
  color:#FBB
  background-color:#F00
}

div.button.green-button{
  color:#BFB
  background-color:#0F0
}
```

[image][image]

In this example it was easy to shift the hue of the first button from red to green by simply changing shifting the values of `color` and `background-color` by 1 digit.  If I wanted to make a blue button I could do the same shift again for a 3rd button.

However, in the case where I don't want to shift completely from one color to the next its a bit trickier.

Additionally I want to color shift everything in the div, not just the `background-color` and `color` properties.  So if I were to place and image in the div the colors of the image would get shifted as well.

Is this possible in CSS? If not can you do it in Javascript?

Comment: Nope, CSS doesn't support black magic. Or is there some logic (color math?) behind it?

Comment: What does "without specifying new values for `color` and `background-color`" mean? How do you want to specify the new color?

Comment: @BoltClock And this question's answers are an example of how reputation-seeking users can sometimes harm the community. I think it's very important practice to only post an answer when you know that it'll contribute positively; and as long as the question is in its current form, I doubt any of the wild guesses are actually helpful.

Comment: @Abody97, I disagree, I did my best to understand what he said even though he didn't make it clear. He now has to wade through a large set of answers in order to figure out which one helps him, which teaches him the lesson of asking more clearly, or wasting _his own_ time. Besides there are at least a couple of technically competent responses to this.

Comment: And if he does accept an answer it means that we can edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @LucasGreen Point taken. This isn't just about the answers, it's about the question as well; it's barely a real question, so even if the answers were helpful to the original poster, this post as a whole (question + answers) wouldn't be too useful to future visitors trying to resolve their problems. It's also not fair, because the "helpful answers" votes will just go to whatever guesses are more likely to be made by more people.

Comment: IMO that's part of the value of online collaboration, you get to utilize a "throw it at the wall and see what sticks" approach to problem solving. Of course that's wasting other peoples time, occasionally, but we are after reputation anyway, and our personal choice is to answer the question, even if it's not clearly stated.

Comment: @Abody97 I also disagree. And using words like "reputation-seeking users", "harm the community" and "contribute (not) positively" is a bit too early... My colleagues (or myself) will ask this sort of question from time to time without giving 4 paragraphs of details: it's just about having another CSS property to use because of existing specificity and HTML classes and whatever in each case. Very very often, there are many ways to solve a problem in CSS

Comment: @LucasGreen I don't think that reputation is a *good* goal; or at least it shouldn't be. StackOverflow (and all collaboratively-maintained Q&A sites) is all about helping others and getting help. It's simple; *you share knowledge*. Reputation is nothing more another "statistic" of how good you're doing. In any case, that's just my opinion!

Comment: @FelipeAls `Very very often, there are many ways to solve a problem in CSS` -- absolutely true. But, can you definitively tell me what the problem is in this case?

Comment: @FelipeAls: I think the issue Abody97 is raising here is that each answer is solving a *different* problem as a different permutation of a single very very vague question (which is the definition of a "wild guess")...

Comment: @Abody97: I don't know about "reputation-seeking" (ironic coming from me, I know), but this is why we have close votes, you know...

Comment: The only reason I bother to help is that I can then show objectively that I am a technically capable person to future employers. Otherwise I would use my time creating things. This system provides incentive for me to help, even though I normally would not. You think that's a bad thing? I don't mind helping people in person, but frankly, helping people online is a can of worms laden with frustrations and communication barriers.

Comment: nothing wrong with "reputation seeking". what else motivates people to answer questions? goodwill?! get real. you're lying to yourself if you think you're not answering questions to pad your rep and invariably corroborate the knowledge you've learned. "goodwill" is a byproduct ...

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for clarification, didn't appear to me as such

Comment: @Xander I see, well if that's your motive, go ahead -- no one can tell you what your motives should be. In my own humble opinion, it's not about that. I answer questions because I think it's useful; I like CSS **a lot** (hence why most my answers in that tag), I like solving challenges, and I like helping people at in the process.

Comment: @Abody97: Wait... how did you know I was reading this question before you pinged me? (Although you're probably aware that mods don't see comment pings unless they've answered, edited or voted to close. And this may be a tongue-in-cheek comment.)

Comment: @Abody97 i like CSS too among ***many*** other things, never said i didn't. if i didn't i wouldn't know so much about it ...

Comment: @Xander No hard feelings :) Like I said, I don't have any issues with other (potentially conflicting) opinions.

Comment: You guys might want to take this discussion to meta. It is a happy place. The OP on the other hand isn't going to be pleased coming back to a dozen irrelevant comments :)

Comment: @BoltClock 22 to be exact ;-)

Comment: @slayton: Heh, I figured there'd be at least a couple of helpful comments, but it seems you won't have any of them. But that's alright - I'll clear these comments soon. You might want to clarify your question though, as it's being interpreted very differently by different people.

Comment: Lost in La Mancha, SO style. Apparently we're not golfers. Nice marmot.

Comment: If you have not already, you should read up on [color theory](http://www.colorsontheweb.com/colorcontrast.asp). @BoltClock - See, I'm contributing.

Comment: You might be interested in [Compass and Sass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/) mixins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since everyone is posting wild guesses, I'll jump right into it.

You could achieve something using [CSS filters](http://davidwalsh.name/css-filters) (in your case `hue-rotate`)

Or the same using a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#-color-functions).

Comment: This seems to be the closest to what the question is asking.

Comment: I've updated my original question, and I think this might be what I'm looking for,

Comment: Note that SVG/CSS filters haven't been widely implemented yet.

Comment: This was a nice tour of CSS filters. Works in every modern browser, and yes I'm excluding Opera Mini, that's a Chaos Browser. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you'll need multiple elements though.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="over-bg"></span>
    <span>A</span>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div, span { height:100px; width:100px; vertical-align:middle;
            text-align:center; }

div { background-color:#ff3300; position:relative; margin:20px; float:left; }
span { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; height:100%; width:100% }
span.over-bg { background-color:#22FF00; display:none; }
div:hover span.over-bg { display:block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TeCvr/1/

---

Another approach using ***pseudo-elements***:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>A</span>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div, span { height:100px; width:100px; vertical-align:middle;
            text-align:center; }

div { background-color:#ff3300; position:relative; margin:20px; float:left; }
span { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; height:100%; width:100% }
div:hover:before { display:block; content:""; position:absolute; left:0;
                   top:0; height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#22FF00; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TeCvr/2/

Comment: `without specifying` **`new`** `values for color and background-color` -- so just because the `background-color` values are pre-defined (not applied on `:hover`), they're considered not to be new? I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: this example fulfills the requirement of *"Is is possible using CSS to change the div to look like this, without specifying new values for color and background-color?"*, in that it doesn't modify the `background-color` or `color` of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HYEhM/)

HTML:

```
<a class="button">A</a>​
```

CSS:

```
.button{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    display:block;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}

.button:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
​
```

Or are you looking for something that figures out the color offset on it's own?

If you are there is CSS3's [`filter: hue-rotate(angle);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter#hue-rotate%28angle%29)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HYEhM/1/)

HTML:

```
<a class="button">A</a>​
```

CSS:

```
.button{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    display:block;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}

.button:hover{
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(250deg);
    -moz-filter:hue-rotate(250deg);
    -ms-filter:hue-rotate(250deg);
    filter:hue-rotate(250deg);
}
​
```

Comment: "without specifying new values for [...] background-color"

Comment: You omitted a logically important word: "and"

Comment: @Prinzhorn if he had said: "without specifying new values for color OR background-color?" the complaint would make sense, but he said: "without specifying new values for color AND background-color?"

Comment: @LucasGreen What do you mean? `color` changes the text's color, and you're not changing the text's color, so where's the surprise there?

Comment: Wow, thanks `filter:hue-rotate` is EXACTLY what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use CSS3 supported transition style rules like:

```
   .button:hover {
     background-color: #F0F0F0;
     -webkit-transition: background-color 1ms linear;
     -moz-transition: background-color 1ms linear;
     -o-transition: background-color 1ms linear;
     -ms-transition: background-color 1ms linear;
     transition: background-color 1ms linear; 
}
```

Is there any specific reason as to why you would like to achieve this..? I can't think of any application as such; unless you came across this while reverse engineering a design and couldn't find the CSS that caused this behaviour..?

Reference:
http://www.css3.info/preview/css3-transitions/

Comment: @slayton Hey I see you hv updated your questions and now it has been closed too :p .. well anyways.. 

You can have the CSS and/or JS shift the background/text colors as per your algo (which is not clear from your question); and you could use HTML5+JS to change the Hue of images as well..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand you. You can change the class of the div. For example .button to .buttongreen with diferent properties.

Comment: Probably not what the OP is looking for (fairly trivial), but, since the question is so vague -- you never know!

Comment: Perhaps is some reason to not be able to use the new class :-?

Answer (score 0):

Without using `color` and `background-color` properties, you can still use:

```
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #006e2e 0%,#006e2e 100%)
```

That's a gradient from a given color to the same color but the whole gradient is not a color in CSS.

Comment: That's a correct answer to the constraints given by OP. Go figure why he has such constraints...

Comment: Well, yes, it meets the constraints if you're going to handle the question literally. I personally suspect he/she mis-phrased his/her question. What kind of case allows using linear gradients but not background colors? Not a normal, sensible case for sure.

Comment: How could I guess that without proposing the answer in the first place? OP will tell me if he can or can't change `background-image` and if not will update his question.